# Normalizing Table Data

Tags: sql, database-normalization

Currently, I have this setup for my tables and relationships:

[image: diagram]

Situation:

There are employees who take courses. They sign in on a roster sheet which is unique to that course. These courses can be taught several times by different instructors. Each course may have multiple rosters with different students (different rosters for different sessions). There are other specifications but for the most part, the employees/instructors table are what I care about.

My problem is that there can be instances where an instructor is also an employee. The only difference between the two tables is the usage of InstructorID rather than EmployeeID. This creates a bit of redundancy with my data. I want to avoid that and try to build this out based on best practices. Is there a way to combine the data in the two tables so that at any point, I could query the tables for all instructors that teach a class with certain employees?

I thought of something like adding in a "isInstructor" field with Yes/No in the Employees table. I could then just check to see if a person has yes or no. However, I feel as though that is a terrible idea. Someone suggested adding in a prefix to the employeeID to designate that they are an instructor. It was also suggested that perhaps I add in an extra field with an identifier for instructors that are also employees.

Essentially, I want to know what the best practice approach to this problem would be. Should I keep the data separated and in two tables or should I combine them and add something in? Any suggestions for the rest of the structure are appreciated as well. This is my first question on here so if more details are needed just let me know.

Comment: I would disconnect Instructors from Department (remove Instructors->DeptID) and drop EmployeeID into Instructors as a Foreign Key.

Comment: Adding a prefix to the EmployeeID is a terrible idea.  Never do this.  This breaks first normal form.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question, I probably should have checked the tutorials for including an image in my question correctly. I will attempt what you suggested and report back here when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both instructors and employees are people. (I deliberately used varchar(5) so you can't use this in production without at least *appearing* to think about names.)

```
create table people (
  p_id integer primary key,
  first_name varchar(5) not null,
  last_name varchar(5) not null,
  dept_id integer not null references departments
);

insert into people values
(1, 'Robin', 'Mings', 1),
(2, 'Ora', 'Black', 1),
(3, 'Sheri', 'Johns', 2),
(4, 'Dex', 'Sims', 3);
```

Best Practice: If you want to use plurals for table names, then always use plurals. If you want to use singulars for table names, always use singulars. (I use plurals.)

Use tables to capture details about whether a person is employed and whether a person is an instructor. The very least you need to know is their id number. Robin Mings and Sheri Johns are instructors.

```
create table instructors (
  p_id integer primary key references people
);

insert into instructors values 
(1), (3);
```

Sheri Johns, an instructor, is not an employee. The others are, though.

```
create table employees (
  p_id integer primary key references people
);

insert into employees values
(1), (2), (4);
```

In the tables "employees" and "instructors", the choice to use "p_id" (the column name in "people") or a column name like "emp_id" is application-dependent.

> These courses can be taught several times by different instructors.

No, they can't. Your design allows only one date per course. Distinguish a course from a class. A class is a course that's offered under a particular instructor, and it starts on a particular date.

```
create table courses (
  course_id integer primary key,
  course_name varchar(5) not null unique,
  course_desc varchar(5) not null,       -- unique?
  course_objectives varchar(5) not null  -- Think about whether this deserves its own table.
);

insert into courses values
(1, 'AP101', 'Desc', 'Obj'),
(2, 'AR101', 'Desc', 'Obj');
```

Best Practice: Don't use words like *list* in your table names. Nobody says, "Are you supposed to be in this class? Let me check my roster list." Also, semantics count. If you use "roster_list" and "course_list" (which in your case are not actually lists of courses or of rosters), why refrain from using "employee_list", "department_list", etc? *List* is just noise here. Choose better words.

```
create table classes (
  course_id integer not null references courses,
  instructor_id integer not null references instructors (p_id),
  start_date date not null,
  -- I have no idea what completion_time means, so I omitted it.
  primary key (course_id, instructor_id, start_date)
);

insert into classes values
(1, 1, '2015-04-01'),
(2, 3, '2015-04-15');
```

In my experience, employees sign up for classes, not for courses. (You used the word *sessions*, but didn't use that in your design.)  Depending on the application, you might need more tables than this one.

```
create table class_rosters (
  course_id integer not null,
  instructor_id integer not null,
  start_date date not null,
  employee_id integer not null references employees (p_id)
    on update restrict on delete cascade,
  primary key (course_id, instructor_id, start_date, employee_id),
  foreign key (course_id, instructor_id, start_date)
    references classes (course_id, instructor_id, start_date) 
    on update cascade on delete cascade
);

insert into class_rosters values 
(1, 1, '2015-04-01', 2),
(1, 1, '2015-04-01', 4),
(2, 3, '2015-04-15', 1), -- An instructor is taking this class.
(2, 3, '2015-04-15', 2),
(2, 3, '2015-04-15', 4);
```

> Is there a way to combine the data in the two tables so that at any
>   point, I could query the tables for all instructors that teach a class
>   with certain employees?

```
-- Instructors who teach a class that has Ora Black in it.
select distinct cr.instructor_id
from class_rosters cr
inner join people p on p.p_id = cr.employee_id
where p.first_name = 'Ora' and p.last_name = 'Black';

-- Instructors who teach a class that has both Ora Black 
-- and Robin Mings (an instructor) in it.
with students as (
  select p_id 
  from people
  where (first_name = 'Ora' and last_name = 'Black')
     or (first_name = 'Robin' and last_name = 'Mings')
)
select instructor_id
from class_rosters cr
inner join students s on s.p_id = cr.employee_id
group by course_id, instructor_id, start_date
having count(*) = (select count(*) from students);
```

```
instructor_id
--
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would disconnect `Instructors` from `Department` (remove `Instructors->DeptID`) and drop `EmployeeID` into `Instructors` as a Foreign Key.  So instructor without EmployeeID (actually with `null` ID) is an outside instructor.

This will still leave `Instructors` in a de-normalized state but should be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: How would I extend this so that the Instructors table is left in a normalized state? With your answer, I can see how it would help my situation but duplicate first/last name data is undesirable. Wouldn't leaving null values inside of a table structure be bad practice? If you could provide your reasoning that would be great.

Comment: As I've said, I do not believe that your use case justifies further denormalization.